# Click to Zoom/Pan and Center node attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I currently have the following code:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
                if(d.group == 2) {

                  node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible")
                    .on("click",function(d){
                        if(d.group == 1){
                            node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 4; }).style("visibility", "visible")
                                .on("click",function(d){
                                    if(d.group==4){
                                        node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 3; }).style("visibility", "visible")
                                            .on("click",function(d){
                                                if(d.group==3){
                                                    node.filter(function(d){return d.group == 6;}).style("visibility","visible")
                                                    .on("click",function(d){
                                                        if(d.group==6){
                                                            node.filter(function(d){return d.group ==5;}).style("visibility","visible");
                                                            link.filter(function(d){return d.value ==6;}).style("visibility","visible");
                                                            texts.filter(function(d){return d.group ==5;}).style("visibility","visible");
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 5; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                                        texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 6; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 4; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                                        texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 3; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                                        }
                                    });
                            link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 3; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                            texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 4; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                            }
                        });
                  link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                   texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                }
```

I am trying to have it so that when you click a node, besides the `.on("click")` functions I already have, I ALSO want to zoom and center or pan and center, depending on the node.

Comment: It sounds like you want the zoom behaviour for that, but first I would simplify your existing code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to simplify it.

Comment: I think Lars is suggesting you write a custom function that is called by the click so something like .on("click", someFunction) where the custom funtion contains the information above.  Also, the code you've written seems to toggle the visability of groups on and off you don't need to an individual function for each group. You could write one function that take the group as a variable and does the toggling.

Comment: I'm still confused. Any examples?